# Get IP address on Chrome App

Tags: javascript, ip-address, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Chrome app, and I need to get the external IP address.

I've tried loading external scripts, but I was getting errors even though I added the sources to `'content_security_policy'` on the `manifest.json` file.

I gave up, and then I tried making an `XMLHttpRequest` request to an IP host/service website, but requests need to be async and I wasn't able to save the response to a variable even using `setTimeout()`.

I was always getting `undefined` because the variable was clearly being set before the request was completed.

So can you please help me find a simple solution to get the IP?

Answer (score 3):

This site **http://jsonip.com/** outputs a `JSON` object like this:

```
{"ip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","about":"/about","Pro!":"http://getjsonip.com"}
```

You can perform an asynchronous `XMLHttpRequest` to that site like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    IP_ADDRESS;

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
        IP_ADDRESS = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).ip;
        console.log('IP ADDRESS: ' + IP_ADDRESS);
        // Log it or do something else so you'll know that the response has been received
    }
}

xhr.open('GET', 'http://jsonip.com/', true);
xhr.send();
```

After a while you'll see a log like this in the console:

```
IP ADDRESS: 12.34.567.89
```

Comment: Your code looks identical to what I had previously done, but the problem is, if I try to `console.log(IP_ADDRESS)` it shows `undefined`. The strange thing is that when I `console.log(xhr)` I can see a whole JSON object with the correct `responseText`, but if I `console.log(xhr['responseText']` it shows `undefined` again. Can you please help me? I need to save the IP in a variable.

Comment: It works fine on my Chrome extension: **http://i.imgur.com/6ZCIt6B.jpg**. Make sure that you copied ALL my code correctly (and use it in your background page).

Comment: I copied your code exactly like you posted it, but if I try to access the IP_ADDRESS variable right after your code I get `undefined` because it's an async request. But I guess it'll do, since I don't need the variable immediately after your code. Cheers!

Comment: Obviously if you call the var right after the request it will be undefined man! You have to create a function to call when the request ends. In that function you know that the variable exists and you can use it... this is basic programming logic.